# How do I preserve whitespace characters when parsing XML from C# LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, whitespace

**What do I need to do in either my C# code or my XML document so that the XDocument parser reads literal whitespace for `Value`s of `XElement`s?**

---

**Background**

I have an XML document, part of which looks like this:

```
    <NewLineString>&#10;&#13;</NewLineString>
    <IndentString>    </IndentString>
```

I'm adding the values of each `XELement` to a data dictionary using a LINQ query; the `.ForEach` part looks like this:

```
    .ForEach(x => SchemaDictionary.Add(
        LogicHelper.GetEnumValue(x.Name.ToString()), x.Value));
```

To test to see if the whitespace values were preserved, I'm printing out a line of the character numbers of each value item in the data dictionary. In the following code, `x` represents a `KeyValuePair` and the `Aggregate` is simply making a string of the character integer values:

```
x.Value.ToCharArray()
    .Aggregate<char,string>("",(word,c) => word + ((int)c).ToString() + " " )
    ));
```

I expected to see `10 13` for the `<NewLineString>` value and `32 32 32 32` for the `<IndentString>` value.  However, nothing was printed for each value (*note: other escaped values in the XML such as `&lt;` printed their character numbers correctly*).

What do I need to do in either my C# code or my XML document so that my parser adds the complete whitespace string to the Data Dictionary?

Comment: How are you loading the XML document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try loading your XDocument with the [LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538371.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try loading your document this way.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    doc.Load("book.xml");
```

Comment: The original question asked about LINQ [`XDocument`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345449.aspx), not System.Xml [`XmlDocument`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kza7w4k.aspx). But [my web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=.NET+XML+preserve+whitespace) for an answer about `XmlDocument`s linked me to this question, so this answer is useful anyway.

Answer (score -3):

or just modify your input xml to:

```
<NewLineString>&#10;&#13;</NewLineString>
<IndentString xml:space="preserve">    </IndentString>
```