# XmlSerializer and embedded WhiteSpace

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have the following xml that contains a white space Field1Value   . When I deserialize that xml I lose the single space character. The value of Request.Field2 is "". Is this a bug in the xml serializer?
Can anyone recommend a solution/ workaround to keep this space?

```
  ...
            var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            var _xmlData = "<Request><Field1>Field1Value</Field1><Field2>   </Field2></Request>";
            var _xmlDataAsByteArray = new byte[_xmlData.Length];
            _xmlDataAsByteArray = encoding.GetBytes(_xmlData);

            var _memoryStream = new MemoryStream(_xmlDataAsByteArray);

           var _XmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Request));

            Request _request = _XmlSerializer.Deserialize(_memoryStream) as Request;

  ...
         public class Request
           {
               public string Field1;
               public string Field2;
           }
```

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not a bug, but expected behavior. Unless you opt-in for preserving space, XML is processors (i.e. the apps reading and writing XML) are supposed to **normalize whitespace**. See section 2.1 of the XML 1.1 specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-white-space).

To preserve the whitespace you have to include the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute. Hence the XML shall look like this:

```
<Request>
   <Field1>Field1Value</Field1>
   <!-- spaces inside Field2 will be preserved -->
   <Field2 xml:space="preserve">   </Field2> 
</Request>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the XmlReader to load the xml with IngoreWhitespace set to false

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request)).Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(_memoryStream, new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = false })) as Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the xml:space attribute can help by setting it to 'preserve'. See [this article](http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=whitespa.sql&id=18238) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking into dealing with preserving whitespace and this answer is useful in that regard: [How do I preserve whitespace characters when parsing XML from C# LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209748/how-do-i-preserve-whitespace-characters-when-parsing-xml-from-c-linq/2209791#2209791)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem. In my case the XML is generated by code I control so I was able to add the xml:space=preserve attribute. I was using IXmlSerializable (for a good reason that I won't go in to here). Here's how I did it, in case this is helpful to someone (it's hard to find examples of much of this Xml serialization/deserialization). This WriteSettings() method is called by my WriteXml() method implementing IXmlSerializable.

```
    public static void WriteSettings(XmlWriter writer, Dictionary<string, string> settings)
    {
        foreach (string key in settings.Keys)
        {
            string value = settings[key];
            writer.WriteStartElement("Setting");
            writer.WriteElementString("SettingType", key);

            //writer.WriteElementString("SettingValue", value);
            // I replaced the above line, which I had previously, 
            // with the below 5 lines. 
            writer.WriteStartElement("SettingValue");
            if (value != value.Trim())
                writer.WriteAttributeString("xml", "space", null, "preserve");
            writer.WriteString(value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
```

This gives me XML that looks like this (enclosing element written by enclosing object, not the WriteSettings method above):

```
<ResourceSettings>
  <Setting>
    <SettingType>SomeSettingName</SettingType>
    <SettingValue>1</SettingValue>
  </Setting>
  <Setting>
    <SettingType>AnotherSettingName</SettingType>
    <SettingValue xml:space="preserve"> </SettingValue>
  </Setting>
  <Setting>
    <SettingType>ADifferentSettingName</SettingType>
    <SettingValue>some other value</SettingValue>
  </Setting>
</ResourceSettings>
```

I read this in using the same code I had before and the XmlReader respects the xml:space=preserve attribute, e.g.:

```
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "ResourceSettings")
        {
            // Deal with the case where there are no settings
            if (reader.ReadToDescendant("Setting"))
            {
                while (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "Setting")
                {
                    reader.ReadStartElement("Setting");
                    string key = reader.ReadElementString("SettingType");
                    string value = reader.ReadElementString("SettingValue");
                    reader.ReadEndElement();
                    _cache.Add(key, value);
                }
            }
            reader.Read(); // move past container
        }
    }
```